# Make fewer false positives for "Your question appears subjective"

Tags: feature-request, subjective-warning

Is it possible to change when the message

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed

appears? At the moment it appears for questions with "how can", which is fair enough, as "How can I create the best app ever!" is highly subjective and basically unanswerable.

However, my question started with "How can I tell **if**..." which changes it from an opinion-based question to a "concrete steps" type question designed to reveal a yes/no condition. Can this be changed to give fewer false positives without sacrificing its current value?

Comment: The current quote is aimed at covering for false positives, but I see what you mean. Some generalisation could do. Probably should be in The main meta though!

Comment: Wow.  I am pretty sure _most_ of my (objective, well-received) questions start with "How can".

Comment: I asked my very first Stack Overflow question today and got the same message. This was the title: *iOS 10.1 Simulator shows “Application May Slow Down Your iPhone”* How on Earth is that supposed to be subjective?

Comment: @Glorfindel i get that alot too and 90% of the time trigger is *"you"*. generally if i know it's not subjective i tend to ignore it since it's only a warning

Comment: @Glorfindel "may" would be the word that flagged it. may = might = not definite = subjective.

Comment: How can I tell if he really loves me?  I fall in love whenever we meet.  I'm asking you 'cause you know about these things?

Comment: @Ramhound disagreed. Including the error message in the title boosts the question when one Googles the error message, I would suppose.